# covert character date to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I've imported some data from package RNCEP that includes a datetime stamp (in UTC) as a character:

```
> head(df.weather[1])
       datetime
1 2018_06_01_00
2 2018_06_01_00
3 2018_06_01_00
4 2018_06_01_00
5 2018_06_01_00
6 2018_06_01_00
```

With year, month, date and hour separated by underscores.

I'd like to change these dates to POSIXct, and I can use the following to get the date:

```
df.weather$date<-as.POSIXct(
  str_replace_all(df.weather$datetime, "_", "-"), 
  format="%Y-%m-%d") 
head(df.weather[11])
       date
1 2018-06-01
2 2018-06-01
3 2018-06-01
4 2018-06-01
5 2018-06-01
6 2018-06-01
```

However, if I change the format to "%Y-%m-%d %H" or "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", I get the following:

```
  date
1 <NA>
2 <NA>
3 <NA>
4 <NA>
5 <NA>
6 <NA>
```

How can I adjust my code to get the hour information into a POSIXct variable?

Comment: `as.POSIXct(strptime(df.weather$datetime, "%Y_%m_%d_%H"))`?

Comment: Unfortunately that still only gives me date, but not the hour associated with it.

Comment: Actually it _did_ give you the hour. But you were fooled by the behavior of print.POSIXt which omits the hour when it prints midnight. Pretty sure this has been asked and answered before, but I looked for one and couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks.  If you put this as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one `as.POSIXct(strptime("2010_10_31_01", "%Y_%m_%d_%H"))`. Probably you want to add a timezone using the `tz` argument. If the hour equals `00` as in your example the time is automatically stripped. Try the same code with `01`.

Comment: hum... when I run your example, I get a useful answer "2010-10-31 01:00:00 GMT", but if I replace my first value for datetime (2018_06_01_00) into the same code, I only get "2018-06-01 GMT".  The problem is the last two numbers (in this case 00) does represent a time and can have values of 06, 12 and 18.

Comment: @user3220999 That's because Jan doesn't understand the problem. You were getting a datetime result.

Comment: I think that answer is correct. As @42 pointed out it just a problem based on the print behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The function that displays datetime values has the infelicity of not printing minutes, seconds, or hours for times at midnight:

```
# First build a test vector of character values
 times <- scan(text="2018_06_01_00
  2018_06_01_00
  2018_06_01_00
  2018_06_01_00
  2018_06_01_00
  2018_06_01_00", what="")
#Read 6 items

# Now run your code
 realTimes<-as.POSIXct(
  str_replace_all(times, "_", "-"), 
  format="%Y-%m-%d") 
 realTimes

#[1] "2018-06-01 PDT" "2018-06-01 PDT" "2018-06-01 PDT" "2018-06-01 PDT"
#[5] "2018-06-01 PDT" "2018-06-01 PDT"

 dput(realTimes)
structure(c(1527836400, 1527836400, 1527836400, 1527836400, 1527836400, 
1527836400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

@ANG's comment was useful (suggesting to use format= "%Y_%m_%d_%H" instead of the more clumsy `str_replace`-ment with "-") but he, too, missed the central issue.